# Solving problem using enhanced aggregate reporting functions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using sqlplus (oracle).
I trying to write a statement to show the change in account value based on the value of all transaction for

- each customer_account_combination
- each customer
- the whole bank

Also, debit transaction should be negative and credit transaction should remain posiive.
I need to solve it using enhanced aggregate reporting functions in oracle.
Plus, there should be customer totals and grand totals.

Here is what I got so far.

```
select wc.first_name "First", wc.surname "Last", wt.account_type "Act Type" 
case when wt.transaction_type is NULL then NULL 
    when wt.transaction_type = 'D'then TO_CHAR(transaction_amount*-1, '$9,999.99') 
    else TO_CHAR(transaction_amount, '$9,999.99') 
    end "Total" 
from wgb_customer wc join wgb_account wa on wa.customer_number = wc.customer_number join wgb_account_type wt on wa.account_type = wt.account_type
left outer join wgb_transaction wt on wt.customer_number = wa.customer_number 
and wt.account_type = wa.account_type
order by 2,3,6;
```

However, it's not working and doesn't show customer totals or grand totals.
Please help!

ERD
[image: ERD]

Expected Output
[image: Expected output]

Comment: Not behind my computer to show you an example right now but what you are looking for is a "GROUP BY CUBE" or a "GROUP BY ROLLUP".  It allows you to generate subtotals and grand totals out of the box.

Comment: Select wc.first_name "First", wc.surname "Last",  wa.account_type "Type",
 SUM(transaction_amount) AS Total
case when wt.transaction_type is NULL then NULL 
    when wt.transaction_type = 'D'then TO_CHAR(transaction_amount*-1, '$9,999.99') 
    else TO_CHAR(transaction_amount, '$9,999.99') 
    end "Total" 
from 
wgb_customer wc, wgb_account wa, wgb_transaction wt
where wc.customer_number=wa.customer_number and wa.account_type= wt.account_type
GROUP BY ROLLUP (first_name, surname, account_type, transaction_amount)
order by 2,3;

Comment: I came up with above comment, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have attached expected output as an image

Comment: It doesn't usually help when OP's paste an image for data. Best practice is to usually give some sample input and expected output which will get you QUICK answers.

Comment: I posted a tested example with the group by rollup. Works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY ROLLUP is the way to go. It allows you to create all possible subtotals and the grand total. Once you have the data aggegated, you just left join to the customer table to retreive the first_name and last_name. Make sure to do a left join in order not to lose the grand total

```
--SAMPLE TABLES AND TEST DATA 

  CREATE TABLE WGB_TRANSACTION (
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER VARCHAR2(7),
    ACCOUNT_TYPE NUMBER(1),
    TRANSACTION_AMOUNT NUMBER,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE VARCHAR2(1)
  );

  CREATE TABLE WGB_CUSTOMER (
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER VARCHAR2(7),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    SURNAME VARCHAR2(30)
   );

INSERT INTO WGB_CUSTOMER VALUES ( '123', 'John','Smith');
INSERT INTO WGB_CUSTOMER VALUES ( '456', 'James','Anderson');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (123,1,100,'C');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (123,1,50,'D');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (123,2,100,'C');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (456,1,50,'C');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (456,1,100,'C');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (456,3,100,'D');
INSERT INTO WGB_TRANSACTION VALUES (456,1,50,'C');

--The Query 
WITH BALANCES AS (
    SELECT CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_TYPE, 
    SUM(DECODE(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'D',-1,'C',1,0)*TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) BALANCE
    FROM WGB_TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ('C','D') 
    GROUP BY ROLLUP ( CUSTOMER_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_TYPE )
)
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME, C.SURNAME, B.ACCOUNT_TYPE, TO_CHAR(B.BALANCE,'$9,999.99')
FROM BALANCES B LEFT JOIN WGB_CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMER_NUMBER=B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER;

--RESULT 
FIRST_NAME  SURNAME ACCOUNT_TYPE    TO_CHAR(B.BALANCE,'$9,999.99')
John    Smith   (null)  $150.00
John    Smith   2   $100.00
John    Smith   1   $50.00
James   Anderson    (null)  $100.00
James   Anderson    3   -$100.00
James   Anderson    1   $200.00
(null)  (null)  (null)  $250.00
```

Answer (score 0):

use union

```
    select wc.first_name "First", wc.surname "Last", wt.account_type "Act Type" 
    case when wt.transaction_type is NULL then NULL 
        when wt.transaction_type = 'D'then TO_CHAR(transaction_amount*-1, '$9,999.99') 
        else TO_CHAR(transaction_amount, '$9,999.99') 
        end "Total" 
    from wgb_customer wc join wgb_account wa on wa.customer_number = wc.customer_number join wgb_account_type wt on wa.account_type = wt.account_type
    left outer join wgb_transaction wt on wt.customer_number = wa.customer_number 
    and wt.account_type = wa.account_type
union 
 select '','',TO_CHAR(total,'$9,999.99') from 
(
select  
       sum ( case when wt.transaction_type is NULL then 0
        when wt.transaction_type = 'D' then transaction_amount*-1 
        else transaction_amount
        end ) as total
    from wgb_customer wc join wgb_account wa on wa.customer_number = wc.customer_number join wgb_account_type wt on wa.account_type = wt.account_type
    left outer join wgb_transaction wt on wt.customer_number = wa.customer_number 
    and wt.account_type = wa.account_type
) t
```